# MySQL: selecting dates (from timestamp) for which condition (related to other fields in the row) is fulfilled

Tags: mysql, timestamp, iteration, days

My SQL knowledge is rather weak and I come from procedural programming, so bear with me. I have a database that contains data from a weather station - these are collected each minute and the (important part of the) table is

```
MariaDB [weather]> describe readings;
+------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| time             | timestamp  | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| inside_temp      | float      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| outside_temp     | float      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

I want to find all days where the outside_temp was not lower and not larger than some values.

I can code it externally using MySQL for queries like

`select min(outside_temp), max(outside_temp) from readings where date(time)='2022-01-27';`

and iterating over all days in the database to check temperature values for each day separately, but I wonder if it is possible to do the selection just using MySQL command (I suppose it is, just beyond my imagination).

Answer (score 0):

Something like `select date(time), min(outside_temp), max(outside_temp) from readings group by date(time);` would give you all timestamps that meet the requirements

Comment: nope, that lists min/max temperatures for each day, not the days where the temperature is within given range (although this could be a way to create a temp table from which selecting the dates I am interested in would be trivial)

Comment: True, you could do this: SELECT * FROM (select date(time) as date, min(outside_temp) as outside_min, max(outside_temp) as outsidemax from readings group by date(time)) where outside_min > 1 and outside_max < 5 or select date(time), min(outside_temp) as outsidemin, max(outside_temp) as outsidemax from readings group by date(time) having outsidemin > 1 and outsidemax < 5